# Neovim :Explore weird behaviour

Tags: neovim, netrw, lsp

I'm new to neovim. I've been using the :Explore command to go to netrw, but when this happens the color scheme becomes inverted and my lsp starts trying to process the netrw buffer. This gets fixed the moment I switch to another directory, or switch focus to another window and back to my terminal. Any suggestions? I have pretty much a barebones configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Vim. It seems to me that your configuration is a little bit more than barebone. LSP is not part of the barebone config to my knowledge. Are you using a "distribution" like NvChad or LazyVim? What is your colorscheme? What LSP servers is interacting with Neovim, for which language?